# AVPlayer does not keep the slo-motion effect

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, slowmotion

After recording a slo-motion video (the activeFormat, the activeVideoMinFrameDuration and the activeVideoMaxFrameDuration properties on the AVCaptureDevice object have been changed to the proper values), the slo-motion effect is missing when the video is played directly after the `didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt` method has been called.

I tried to reduce the rate of the player and the video slows down but it's not the same as if I saved the video into the Library and then I play it.

Any idea on how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Kindly help me.